# simple explanation about .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I using it and use RewriteEngine
and i saw recently some text in the right side of RewriteEngine
like that
[L,QSA]
what this mean
and [L]
can eny one give me full list of them and usage for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're documented at the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) page:

> **'last|L' (last rule)**
> Stop the rewriting process here and don't apply any more rewrite rules. This corresponds to the Perl last command or the break command in C. Use this flag to prevent the currently rewritten URL from being rewritten further by following rules. Remember, however, that if the RewriteRule generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first RewriteRule.
>
> **'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)**
> This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a good cheat sheet [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/) which I've found helpful.